# “Students avoid boring professors” is ambiguity?

Tags: ambiguity

Wondering how “Students avoid boring professors” is ambiguious?

I know there is one meaning of this sentence, "stay away from".
Is there any other possible meanings?

Comment: To 'avoid doing something' means to 'make sure you don't do that thing'. So one reading here is 'Students manage / make sure not to bore their professors.' It's a catenative structure: 'avoid boring' cf 'stop teasing'. Your sense uses 'boring' as a participial adjective. The classic example in this area is 'Flying planes can be dangerous.'

Comment: Another is _Visiting relatives can be boring_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ambiguity comes from the word "boring," which can be interpreted as an adjective or a noun (see [gerund](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)).

You read the sentence as:

> Students avoid professors who are boring.

(Which I think is the most natural interpretation, unless there is further context.) Here "boring" is an adjective, modifying "professors."

However, it can also be interpreted as:

> Students avoid making their professors bored.

Here "boring" is a noun, referring to the act of making someone feel bored.

Answer (score 3):

The two possible meanings:

1. Students stay away from boring professors.
2. Students try hard not to bore their professors.

But I believe everyone else has told you the same. :-)

Comment: So why answer at all? :) One comment and two other answers had already  given this information, so you haven't meaningfully *added* anything.

Comment: Because when one reads the other answers here, there's a good chance they'd get lost in such a blizzard of words. I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If *boring* is taken as an adjective, it means "Students stay away from professors who are boring." But *boring* can also be taken as the gerund form of the verb *to bore*, in which case the sentence would mean "Students do not bore professors."